# Turn-by-Turn Directions - Providing Alternate Routes to a Driver (TomTom) - Patent Application - PRIOR ART REQUEST

Tags: prior-art-request, pre-grant, rejected, us20130173159a1, tomtom

[image]

This Patent Application has received a **non-final rejection** by the US Patent Office! An initial rejection is part of the typical course of a patent application.

---

**AN OVERBROAD PATENT ON a navigation device with alternative route calculation** - This application from TomTom seeks to patent the idea of...providing a navigation instruction together with alternative navigation instructions to a destination! 10 minutes of your time can help narrow US patent applications before they become patents.  [Follow @askpatents](https://twitter.com/AskPatents) on twitter to help.

**QUESTION** - Have you seen anything that was **published before 9/13/2010** that discusses:

> - providing alternate routes to a driver without the driver being required to request a calculation of an alternative route

If so, please submit evidence of prior art as an answer to this question. We welcome multiple answers from the same individual.

**EXTRA CREDIT** - A reference to anything that meets all of the criteria to the question above AND ALSO displays multiple potential navigation routes simultaneously

**TITLE: Navigation device with alternate route calculation**

**Summary**:  [Translated from Legalese into English] A navigation device that calculates multiple routes for a driver and displays them simultaneously (without the driver being required to request a different route)

- **Publication Number**: [US20130173159 A1](https://www.google.com/patents/US20130173159?dq=US20130173159A1)
- **Application Number**: US 13/822,791
- **Assignee**: TomTom
- **Prior Art Date**: Seeking prior Art **predating** 9/13/2010
- **Open for Challenge at USPTO:** Open through 12/31/2013

**Claim 1** requires each and every step below:

> A navigation device, the navigation device operable to calculate routes to one or more destinations,
>
> 1. the device further operable to provide a navigation instruction together with
> 2. an alternative navigation instruction.

In English this means:

> A navigation device which calculates routes to destination (or multiple destinations), which:
>
> 1. provides navigation instructions; and
> 2. provides instructions on alternative routes

Good prior art would be evidence of a system that did each and every one of these steps prior to 9/13/2010

You're probably aware of ten pieces of art that meet this criteria already... separately, the applicant is claiming displaying multiple routes simultaneously without the driver requesting a "re-route"

---

**"Providing multiple routes to a driver" from the Applicant**

[image]

---

*What is good prior art? Please see our [FAQ](https://patents.stackexchange.com/faq#prior-art).*

*Want to help? Please vote or comment on submissions below. We welcome you to [post your own request for prior art](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prior-art-request+pre-grant) on other questionable US Patent Applications.*

---

Answer (score 6):

My 2006 Infiniti G35 Coupe had a navigation system that provided both of the features shown in the claims. It showed a map with different colored lines for the fastest and shortest routes along with another for a route with no freeways.

Edit
I found this in page 5-3 of [2008 C35 Nav user manual.](https://owners.infinitiusa.com/iowners/content/manualsandguides/G_Sedan/2008/2008-Infiniti-06IT-Navi.pdf)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The google maps website made any laptop a device that did this in 2009.  It showed multiple routes, and gave navigation instructions for each route.  This blog post announced the feature on May 22, 2009:
http://google-latlong.blogspot.com/2009/05/would-you-like-some-extra-suggestions.html

The screenshot in the announcement shows a map with multiple routes calculated, times and distances for each route, and navigation instructions for the selected route.

Answer (score 1):

The [Waze](http://www.waze.com/) application for Android and iOS precisely performs both claims 1 and 2.

1) Waze provides navigation instructions.  From their home page:

> Waze is the world's fastest-growing community-based traffic and
>   navigation app.

2) [Waze presents the user with alternate routes, and will change recommended routing on the fly](http://www.waze.com/wiki/?title=How_Waze_calculates_routes).

> Since Waze uses the time you expect to be at a road segment to
>   calculate the expected speed on that segment, it cannot use real time
>   data when you trip time moves into a future time slot. So trips of
>   more than 30 minutes (and on average more than 15 minutes) will
>   include future time slots where current traffic data is not available
>   when initially calculated. When you enter a new time slot, real-time
>   traffic data may be available which may cause your client to
>   recalculate your ETA and reroute you at that point.

[Waze was created in 2006.](http://www.waze.com/faq/)

Answer (score 1):

Weihua Zhu discusses intelligent re-routing of navigation systems for environmental concerns in his dissertation "[Design and Development of Novel Routing Methodologies for Dynamic Roadway Navigation Systems](http://www.uctc.net/research/diss148.pdf)" published in March 2009.